# Add new column in google DataView dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google chart datatable getting data from a Json, but I want to add a new column result of divide column 2 by 15000.

Using google.visualization.DataTable()

I'm getting something like this

```
Colum 1            | Column 2
First row            15.000.000€
Second row           20.000.000€
```

I want Column 3 like this

```
Colum 1            | Column 2          | Column 3
First row            15.000.000€         1.000,00€
Second row           20.000.000€         1.333,33€
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `DataView` to add the new column, using a calculated column.

create a data view from the data table

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
```

then use the `setColumns` method to change the view columns.
we use the column index of the first two columns,
then use a calculation for the third.

```
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return dt.getValue(row, 1) / 15000;
  },
  label: 'Column 3',
  type: 'number'
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    ['First Row', 15000000],
    ['Second Row', 20000000]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1) / 15000;
    },
    label: 'Column 3',
    type: 'number'
  }]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  table.draw(view);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

to format the number,
use google's number formatter,
and object notation for the value.

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: '#,##0.00',
  suffix: '€'
});
```

to format a data table column, use the `format` method.

```
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
```

to format a single value, use the `formatValue` method.

```
  var value = dt.getValue(row, 1) / 15000;
  return {
    v: value,
    f: formatNumber.formatValue(value)
  };
```

see following working snippet..

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    ['First Row', 15000000],
    ['Second Row', 20000000]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.00',
    suffix: '€'
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var value = dt.getValue(row, 1) / 15000;
      return {
        v: value,
        f: formatNumber.formatValue(value)
      };
    },
    label: 'Column 3',
    type: 'number'
  }]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  table.draw(view);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Works well, very thanks!, but, any way to apply NumberFormat to column 3? Limit 2 decimals and suffix €?

Comment: Work perfect! Thanks!!